problem installing ggiraph on Ubuntu 24.04
I was able to successfully install ggiraph on a system running Ubuntu 20.04 (R version 4.3.3) but not Ubuntu 24.04 (R version 4.4.2).
install.packages("ggiraph") gives this error:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:181:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/print.h: In function ‘void Rcpp::warningcall(SEXP, const std::string&)’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/print.h:30:19: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   30 |     Rf_warningcall(call, s.c_str());
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:204: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ggiraph’


devtools::install_github('davidgohel/ggiraph') gives this error:
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: .make_numeric_version(x, strict, .standard_regexps()$valid_numeric_version)
  error: invalid non-character version specification 'x' (type: double)


Check to see what C compiler requirements might have changed. Look at the system dependencies and requirements of versions for libraries.
